# Fatal error in launcher : while using Django

Tags: python, django, installation

When running the command

> "pip install openpyxl"

in PowerShell on Windows, I encountered the following error:

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using

> '"C:\Python311\python.exe" "C:\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe" install
> openpyxl':

The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I resolve this issue and successfully install the "openpyxl" package using pip?

[Screen Capture Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnpIH.png)

I'm working on a Django project and I want to integrate Excel functionality. I'm trying to display data from my database, but I'm encountering the following error: "Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python311\python.exe" "C:\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe" install openpyxl': The system cannot find the file specified."

I believe this error is related to installing the openpyxl package using pip. Can someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully work with Excel in Django? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Can you try same thing inside the virtual environment of pipenv [Reference](https://medium.com/co-learning-lounge/create-virtual-environment-python-windows-2021-d947c3a3ca78)

This issue seems to be in conflict with the local Python environment with the openpyxl library.

Comment: Thankyou it's work when install inside the virtual environment.